# BMI Calculator Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a BMI calculator but I'm having problems when I run the program because my result is:

**nullweighs 0.0 and measures  0.0 tall. Your BMI is**

When it should state the name, weight, BMI and whether it's underweight, healthy, overweight, or obese.

Here is the code:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private double  heightInches;
    private double weightPounds;


    public Person (String userFirstName, double userHeightInches, double userWeightPounds)
    {


        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.heightInches = heightInches;
        this.weightPounds = weightPounds;


    }



    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public double getHeightInches()
    {
        return this.heightInches;
    }

    public double getWeightPounds()
    {
        return this.weightPounds;
    }

    public void setFirstName (String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setHeightInches(double userHeightInches)
    {
        this.heightInches = userHeightInches;
    }

    public void setWeightPounds(double userWeightPounds)
    {
        this.weightPounds = userWeightPounds;
    }





    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.firstName + "weighs " + this.weightPounds + " and measures  "
               + this.heightInches + " tall. Your BMI is "; 
    }



     public double calculateBMI(double userHeightInches,  double userWeightPounds )

    {


    double BMI = ((userWeightPounds / userHeightInches) * (userHeightInches)) * 703;
    return BMI;


    }
```

and....

```
public class BodyMassIndex {
    public static Person anyPerson;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {

          createPersonObject();
          displayBMI();

    }

    public static void createPersonObject()
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        String firstName = keyboard.next();


        System.out.println ("How tall are you (in inches)?");
        Double heightInches = keyboard.nextDouble();



        System.out.println("How much do you weigh (in pounds)?");
        Double weightPounds = keyboard.nextDouble();

        anyPerson = new Person(firstName, heightInches, weightPounds);
    }

    public static void displayBMI()
    {


        double userWeightPounds = 0;
        double userHeightInches = 0;


        double BMI = anyPerson.calculateBMI(userWeightPounds, userHeightInches);

        System.out.println(anyPerson.toString());

        if (BMI < 18.5)
        {
            System.out.println("Underweight");
        }

        else if (BMI >= 18.5 && BMI < 24.9) {
            System.out.println("Healthy");
        }

        else if (BMI >= 25 && BMI < 29.9) {
            System.out.println("Overweight");
        }

        else if (BMI >= 30) {
            System.out.println("Obese");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should debug your program.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting your field variables to themselves, which are not instantiated and so have the value of null or 0.0. You need to set them to the parameters of your class: this.firstName = **user**FirstName.

Your BMI calculation is also off since your automatically using values of 0.0 and 0.0. You should be using the getter methods in your `Person` class to do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Should you be calculating BMI as below?:

```
public static void displayBMI() {

  /* This code is no longer needed */
  double userWeightPounds = 0;
  double userHeightInches = 0;

  double BMI = anyPerson.calculateBMI(anyPerson.getWeightPounds(), anyPerson.getHeightInches());
  ...
```

You can also simplify the code a bit further to make `Person` calculate the BMI without having to request for the weight and height as a parameter:

```
public double calculateBMI() {
   return ((this.weightPounds / this.heightInches) * (this.heightInches)) * 703;

}
```

It would be good to have a check for zero inputs as well.